# Android default method to get date and times properly for 1 day and 1 hour

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, simpledateformat, dateformatter

I have written if-else conditions for displaying date and time when it comes to 1 day, 1 hour, etc. I want to know whether there are any functions that would do that without adding these conditions. I am posting my code here

```
if(days.toInt() == 0 && hours.toInt() > 1)
            {
                result = "$hours hours"
            }
            else if(hours.toInt() == 0 && days.toInt() > 1)
            {
                result = "$days days"
            }
            else if(days.toInt() == 1 && hours.toInt() > 1)
            {
                result = "$days day $hours hours"
            }
            else if(hours.toInt() == 1 && days.toInt() > 1)
            {
                result = "$days days $hours hour"
            }
            else if(days.toInt() == 1 && hours.toInt() == 0)
            {
                result = "$days day"
            }
            else if(days.toInt() == 0 && hours.toInt() == 1)
            {
                result = "$hours hour"
            }
            else if(days.toInt() == 1 && hours.toInt() == 1)
            {
                result = "$days day $hours hour"
            }
            else if(hours.toInt() == 0 && days.toInt() ==0)
            {
                result = ""
            }
            else if(hours.toInt() > 1 && days.toInt() > 1)
            {
                result = "$days days $hours hours"
            }
            return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are such functions, but you can make your if - else cascade a lot simpler, for example by defining this function

```
private String my_formatter(int val, String strPlaceholder) {
    String ret = "";
    if ( val == 1 )
            result = "1 " + strPlaceholder;
        else
            result = val + " " + strPlaceholder + "s";
    return ret;
}
```

and then you can just do like this

```
result = "";
if(days.toInt() > 0) {
    result = result + my_formatter(days.toInt(), "day");
}
if(hours.toInt() > 0) {
    result = result + my_formatter(hours.toInt(), "hour");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ICU [MessageFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/MessageFormat) from `android.icu.text.MessageFormat` (not the one from `java.text`). The syntax of the format string is described in http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages

```
MessageFormat.format(
        "{days,plural,=1{# day} other {# days}}{hours,plural,=0{} =1{ # hour} other { # hours}}", mapOf<String, Any?>(
            "days" to 2,
            "hours" to 0
        ))
```

There is also [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/RelativeDateTimeFormatter#combineDateAndTime(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which you might want to look at, but that gives a slightly different English string than in your example.

```
 RelativeDateTimeFormatter fmt = RelativeDateTimeFormatter.getInstance();
 fmt.format(1, Direction.NEXT, RelativeUnit.DAYS); // "in 1 day"
```

Comment: where to give the start and end date in RelativeDateTimeFormatter..or how to use that format? @maurice

Comment: The first argument is the relative duration. That is like the `days` or `hours` variable you mentioned in your question. You will need to compute that if you are given the start and end dates

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

I recommend you do it using the modern date-time API:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getDateTimeDifference("2020-12-20T20:20:50", "2020-12-23T17:10:40"));

    }

    static String getDateTimeDifference(String strStartDateTime, String strEndDateTime) {
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strStartDateTime);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strEndDateTime);
        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);

        // #################### Since Java-8 ####################
        String formattedDurationJava8 = String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds", duration.toDays(),
                duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDurationJava8);
        // ######################################################

        // #################### Since Java-9 ####################
        String formattedDurationJava9 = String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds", duration.toDaysPart(),
                duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDurationJava9);
        // ######################################################

        // return formattedDurationJava8;
        return formattedDurationJava9;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 days 20 hours 49 minutes 50 seconds
2 days 20 hours 49 minutes 50 seconds
2 days 20 hours 49 minutes 50 seconds
```

### Some important notes:

1. [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.
2. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [**ThreeTen-Backport**](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).
3. Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.